# getting hidden fields value

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, struts2

I am working on a Struts2 application. I am setting the value of a hidden field in JSP with the purpose to access it by JavaScript.

My JSP code:

```
<s:iterator value="collegelist">
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><s:property value="collegename"/></td>
        <s:hidden name="hiddenname" key="collegename" />  
    </tr> 
</s:iterator>
```

My JS code:

```
var myForm = document.frmAction;
var text = myForm.hiddenname.value;
alert("hidden field text is:" + text);
```

The alerts shows a blank value.

What is the cause and how can I solve this?

Comment: Did you incorrectly spell `document.frmAction`?

Comment: it is correct: var myForm = document.frmAction;

Comment: @singh: alert(myForm); does it shows null?

Comment: @ Suresh S: alert(myForm); shows: [object HTMLFormElement]

Comment: @Singh why dont u use Javascript library like jQuery or Prototype.Meanwhile try using document.getElementById("<hiddenfieldid>").value;

Comment: does your hidden element even contain any value.. i tried this and it works  http://jsbin.com/ajajo4/edit

Comment: some thing wrong is also here:
<s:hidden name="hiddenname" value='<s:property value="collegename"/>' /> 
it show on alert <s:property value="collegename"/> it not print the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generate multiple fields having the same name, since your code is inside a `s:iterator` tag. You should obviously have such a loop in your Javascript as well :

```
var hiddenFields = document.getElementsByName("hiddenname");
for (var i = 0; i < hiddenFields.length; i++) {
    alert("hidden field text is::" + hiddenFields[i].value);
}
```

Also, verify the the value is not blank in the generated HTML, and that the hidden fields'a name is hiddenname.

Comment: some thing wrong is also here:
<s:hidden name="hiddenname" value='<s:property value="collegename"/>' /> 
it show on alert <s:property value="collegename"/> it not print the value

Comment: You can't have a tag as an attibute of another tag. Try <s:hidden name="hiddenname" value="collegename"/>

Comment: college name will be generate at run time. please suggest

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
element = document.getElementsByName("hiddenname");
alert(element[0].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it surely works.. problem is somewhere in your server code itself..

Look here: http://jsbin.com/ajajo4/2/edit

Comment: Hi Shekhar thanks for your response.

problem is also there
<s:hidden name="hiddenname" value='<s:property value="collegename"/>' />

 it display on alert <s:property value="collegename"/> it is not print the value of collegename

college name will be generate dynamically from the list.
so i thing i can only use <s:property value=""> tag to send the value in hidden field. but it is not working.

please review.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have only one form with the name "frmAction" and only one hidden field with the name "hiddenname". If you have multiple, you'll get an array instead of a single value.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is that you are inside of an iterator. Struts updates the name for you in order to correctly hook everything up. If you pull up your page and view source, your hidden field will probably look something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="collegelist[0].hiddenname" value="thename"/>
```

Regardless, if you want the retrieval by name to work, do not trust the name that you supply to a struts tag. Always pull up the generated source and look at what name the field actually has.

Comment: how assign the hidden value using Struts2 tag inside of iteration. my JSP code look like this:<s:iterator value="collegelist"> <s:hidden name="hiddenname" value='<s:property value="collegename"/>'/> </s:iterator>it take hidden field value as a string it show on alert: java script code: var text = myForm.hiddenname.value; alert(text); please suggest